# How might I set the bottom 3 bytes of a 4-byte long while leaving the top byte intact?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-and

Relevant code is this:

```
typedef unsigned long int chunk_head;

typedef struct malloc_chunk
{
    // Contains the size of the data in the chunk and the flag byte.
    chunk_head      head;

    // Deliberately left unsized to allow overflow. 
    // Contains the payload of the chunk.
    unsigned int    data[];
};
```

And just as an example, the "get" macro is this:

```
//Get the size of the data contained within the chunk.
#define GET_CHUNK_SIZE(chunk) ((chunk.head) & 0xFFFFFF)
```

The upper byte I'm using the bits for flags -- "inuse" and "can be coalesced", and any additional ones that I find will be useful.

Now that I'm done providing background information, as I stated in the title, I need to be able to change the lower 3 bytes to how large the chunk is. My initial instinct was to bitwise AND the header with the size, since it would be properly aligned, but then I realized it might overwrite the flag bytes too, because it automatically prepended zeroes until it size matched the long. I'm not even sure you *can* bitwise AND an int and a long. Anyway, help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about:

```
head = (head & 0xff000000) | (new_size & 0x00ffffff)
```

Comment: I know the size will never exceed 3 bytes (15 bits, to be exact), so I can safely discard the "& 0x00ffffff" portion, correct?

Comment: Yes; if it's impossible for the size to exceed three bytes or you have checks in your code to guarantee that it won't exceed three bytes, then you can discard that `&`.  If it's _possible_ for the new size to exceed three bytes, you might consider using an assertion to help find errors during debugging, per AndreyT's suggestion.

Answer (score 5):

For some reason most of the responses you received so far insist on sweeping the potential size overflow issue under the carpet, i.e. they "and" the chunk size with `0x00FFFFFF` thus quietly discarding the excessive size bits (if any) and then proceed to write the completely meaningless tail portion of the size into the field. I don't know why would anyone do something like that.

The more reasonable code might look as follows

```
assert((size & 0xFF000000) == 0);
chunk.head = (chunk.head & 0xFF000000) | size;
```

There is no valid reason to "and" the size with `0x00FFFFFF`. You should either abort or at least assert on excessive size, not quietly discard the excess.

Answer (score 3):

Use bit fields to do this.  It avoids having to use the macros, nice in the debugger too:

```
typedef struct chunk_head {
  unsigned size:24;
  unsigned inuse:1;
  unsigned cancoalesce:1;
  // Room for 6 more...
};

typedef struct malloc_chunk {
  struct chunk_head head;
  int data[];
};
```

Comment: Only reason I didn't do this (believe me, I considered using them for a long time) was that by all reports, the compiler produces more optimized code for masks than it does for bit fields. And because I need to eke out every last ounce of performance I can, I opted for the speedier code.

Answer (score 0):

#### `chunk.head = (chunk.head & ~0xffffffL) | (new_lower_bits)`

Answer (score 0):

```
#define SET_CHUNK_SIZE(chunk, size) (chunk.head = (chunk.head & 0xFF000000) | (size & 0x00FFFFFF))
```

Is that what you meant or did I miss something?

Comment: Almost right, but the `|=` means you could never clear bits in the size portion.  I suspect `=` is more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

```
// retain the old top 8 bits
chunk.head &= 0xFF00000000

// set the lower 24 bits
chunk.head |= (0x00FFFFFF & new_bits)
```